# collection select based on first drop down value selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, drop-down-menu

how to populate drop-down options based on selected value from first drop-down?

I have the following in my view where for now I select a product and color but I want to limit color options to the selected product

```
<td><%= f.collection_select(:product_id, Product.active.all, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Select Product') %></td>
<td><%= f.collection_select(:color_id, Color.all, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Select Color') %></td>

Product has_many :colors
Color has_and_belongs_to_many :products
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this railscast helps you:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus

Comment: Thanks. I tried before but it's too old. I ignore everything before Rails 3 and using jQuery (JS is not my cup of tea).